# ExtJS, OpenLayers: modify url protocol before it is sent

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, openlayers, extjs3

I'm trying to get a value from combobox inside a formPanel to pass it to a protocol url (of openlayers.protocol.http). This is  the url, based on http://jsbin.com/ireqed/2/edit, that I want to get (in the case I'd choose "cars" in the combobox and enter "cool" in textfield):

```
http://www.mop.org/fs/cars?format=GeoJSON&comments__ilike=cool&queryable=comments
```

after testing, I finally can get the URL I want after choosing one value in combobox and entering a word in textfield (as above).

To send this new URL in the protocol in formPanel, I use an autoLoad call in the handler function of my search button, I think this is sending the url but it's not catched by the protocol itself (ie. XMLHttpRequest.js) but for ExtJS. So, the GeoJSON output is displayed in the formPanel. I attached three PNGs to show this: [image: formPanel before pressing 'search' button], [image: formpanel after pressing 'search' button], [image: output in firebug].

In firebug, once 'search' button is pressed two URLs are called, the first one is the URL I want to replace in the url of the protocol, but it goes to ext-base.js, which is the wrong place. The second one, I actually don't know why is sent, goes to XMLHttpRequest.js which is the right place, but it shouldn't be sent.

So, before the url must be sent in the first place, I need to change it, how could I do it? btw it seems to me it is replacing an inexistent url which belongs to ExtJS, pls help, thanks

**UPDATE #1:**

getting closer... because adding `OpenLayers.loadURL(myurl, {}, null, function(response){});` in the handler function sents the url to XMLHttpRequest.js (right place), but just immediately another url (from the formpanel) is sent to the same place and this covers the right one, is there a way to add some timing to the openlayers.loadurl function? I understand this function works asynchronously (that's why is faster and gets submitted first than the second one), is there a way to just overwrite the second one?
[image: two urls sent, the first one is the right one]

Comment: add a `name` to the combobox config :)

Comment: @A1rPim thanks for the answer, but that's not the problem, I edited the question to explain it better [I think so =)]

Comment: Try to create your example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ext.getCmp('idcombo').getValue() will return currently selected value. But where exactly in a code do you want to get combo value?

Comment: @AvinashT. thanks for your answer, I followed your suggestion and created an example in jsbin.com, here it is: http://jsbin.com/ireqed/2/edit. This code has some improvements, I now can get the URL I want but don't know how to replace it inside the formpanel. I tried jsfiddle.net but no luck to create it. I edited my original question to add more details and figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to take the protocol outside the formPanel and use only "protocol.options.url = newUrl;", a complete explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664759/how-can-i-overwrite-the-url-of-openlayers-protocol-http)